# Can we create Database Scoped credential inside T-SQL procedure on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

Can we create database scoped credential for shared access signature inside a T-SQL procedure on Azure SQL ?

We are trying to bulk insert data from csv file stored on Azure blob

Below are the steps

- Create SAS credentials using JAVA
- Java will call stored procedure to create/alter external  data source and pass SAS credential to this procedure as a parameter
- Above procedure will internally call another procedure to do BULK INSERT

We are facing challenges in creation of database scoped credential via T-SQL procedure , can someone confirm if this approach is actually possible

It would be great help if we can get some sample code for the same .

I've seen the syntax to create database scoped credential on Microsoft site , it works when we run scripts as standalone statements but we are unable to compile the code using a procedure

We tried below code

```
CREATE procedure prc_create_external_data_source @SAS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

SET nocount ON

DECLARE @command varchar(MAX);

PRINT 'Shared Access Key Received Key: '+@SAS;



SET @command = 

'CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential 
WITH IDENTITY = ''SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'',
SECRET = '+@SAS


EXECUTE (@command);

PRINT 'Database Scoped Credential Created';



END
```

We get below Error message after executing this procedure

```
EXECUTE prc_create_external_data_source '1245632512344'
```

Error Number :        102  Error Message : Incorrect syntax near '1245632512344'. Line Number :          3 Procedure Name :  (SQL State: S0001 - Error Code: 0)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your secret probably needs to be surrounded by quotes. Also this all needs to be on one line or concatenated with `+`

If you printed the string it might be obvious. Try this:

```
SET @command =     
'CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential ' +
'WITH IDENTITY = ''SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE''' + 
',SECRET = '''+ @SAS + ''''
```

Comment: Thanks , this works now I get permission error to create database scoped credential.
will check that out..any pointers ?

Comment: According to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql it requires `control` permission on the database

Comment: Example here for master database: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b8ac90d6-8af2-4c87-85a3-3a3a94e0edd6/grant-control-permission-to-master-database?forum=sqlsecurity