# Can we access Azure key vault secrets within Azure Sql Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, bulkinsert, azure-keyvault

I am performing **BULK INSERT** from ADLS Gen2 in Azure Sql Database . And for that I need to create a **DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL** for defining **External Data Source** which required **SAS Token** of ADLS Gen2 as per [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-scoped-credential-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current#examples). And as per my requirement I have to access different **External Data Source**. So I wanted to automate this (process of defining different **External Data Source**) and make it dynamic and hence thought of accessing those SAS token from Azure key vault. But I didn't find any solution or other way around any concrete evidence to rule this approach out.

Please let me know In case anyone has better way of achieving the same.

Comment: do you have a SAS token handy? or need to get the SAS token through Script?

Comment: @DelliganeshS-MT , No SAS token will be stored in Azure Key Vault, I need to fetch that in Azure Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible to *access* a secret in **Azure Key Vault** from Azure SQL Database. There is no access to the underlying CLR unless you are on a managed instances

You have a azure key vault details
**Create a procedure** to add *dynamic external data source key value*.

```
CREATE  proc usp_Create_External_DS @Identity VARCHAR(100), @Secret VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
SET  nocount  ON
DECLARE @command varchar(MAX);
PRINT  'ADL Identity & Secret: '+@Identity+  ','+@Secret;
SET @command =
'CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL ADL_User WITH IDENTITY = '+ @Identity +',SECRET = '+@Secret
EXECUTE (@command);
PRINT  'ADL Scoped Credential Created';
END
```

Please refer: [sql server - Can we create Database Scoped credential inside T-SQL procedure on Azure - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109895/can-we-create-database-scoped-credential-inside-t-sql-procedure-on-azure)

Also Use **ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL** command for rotating storage keys:

[SQL Data Warehouse: ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL command for rotating storage keys | Azure updates | Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/alter-database-scoped-credential-now-supported-sqldw/)

Comment: Thanks @DelliganeshS-MT, I had decided to use this approach however I faced another issue as I need to call this proc from ADF and there I have to pass the secret from outside(i.e. from ADF), there secret will be visible(which is not safe) as it will be logged in pipeline monitor section.

Answer (score 0):

Per this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/calling-http-endpoints-in-t-sql-using-curl-extension/ba-p/385878) you can make an HTTP call to get into Key Vault to obtain the correct SAS token via T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks @MattSmall for the article, got to learn new thing. However It will not work in my case as I am not using Azure Sql Database(Managed Instance). As a last option I can pass the SAS token of different Storage Account as parameter.